# MATLAB/Octave wont shorten long number

Tags: matlab, octave

First time MATLAB user. I have the following line of code in a program: `fprintf(' %f \n', theta);`, which results in: `54368060014147057099990006162582731726551435187805485739626788851124752751305908629414787531387170724584430890347208920495727355767424024576.000000 
 96634004613961676168033871650545168736179521715016065704930661265088994623792769400086691341222852173497032761334151797022979375128799175802329679263694848.000000 
 96634004613961604716879918495205400175451911092618320604570340258974396712180229146522112641753397515611983395520602911824055392738443597616851179928551424.000000`.

Though my current format is set to short, it still prints these very long numbers. What can I do to to get it to print out something like '5.4368e+139' instead?

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807250/matlab-wont-shorten-answer-after-format-short), but I cannot use `VPA` because I don't have `Symbolic Math Toolbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is `fprintf` you should modify the number representation inside it. So, You can write:

```
fprintf('%.5e',theta);
```